# XSS / SQL Injection Attacks with Character Encoding Mixups

Tags: xss, sql-injection, encoding, unicode

Are there any character encoding mixup attacks that are still a threat in 2020?  Such as with XSS or SQL injection being the most obvious.

Some examples:

1. Tricking a browser to display a page in UTF-7 despite XSS filtering was done in UTF-8.

   - `+ADw-script+AD4-` processed as UTF-8 with `htmlspecialchars()` in PHP would go through just fine but if the browser handles as UTF-7 it would be interpreted as `<script>`
   - Or instead of UTF-7, what about other locale/language specific encodings that are not compatible with UTF-8 that could be specially crafted to create special characters like `<` or `"`?
   - Modern browsers default to the UTF-8 encoding if not specified by the server, but maybe the default could be overridden if able to inject the UTF-7 Byte Order Mark `+/v8` (which wouldn't be escaped by `htmlspecialchars()` somewhere in the beginning of the document?  Any other Byte Order Marks or special UTF-8 sequences that have special meaning that could be leveraged?
   - See also: http://michaelthelin.se/security/2014/06/08/web-security-cross-site-scripting-attacks-using-utf-7.html
2. Crafting Illegal UTF-8 sequences in requests to servers that fail to handle them safely, possibly causing the server to skip escapes or create unescaped special HTML characters like `<` or `"`

   - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Invalid_byte_sequences
3. Double encoding parameters in hope the server only does 1 round of escaping any special characters
4. Presenting a URL in unicode with characters that look like normal ASCII letters, but clicking on it goes to a different page, potentially malicious:

   - Fake: [http://www.gooɡle.com/](http://www.goo%C9%A1le.com/)
   - Real: http://www.google.com/
5. Inserting a URL encoded NULL byte `%00` in a parameter to an HTTP request which might cause a filter written in a language like C to interpret it as End-of-String, potentially prematurely ending the filter function leaving trailing characters unchecked.

Can anyone think of any other encoding mixup attacks that I didn't mention? And are any of these actual threats now-a-days, or are they mostly issues of the past?

Comment: Unicode full width less than can sometimes get you XSS. Very rare, mostly happens with SQL Server when the data is in a VARCHAR field (not NVARCHAR)